# Json Post request with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, c, asp.net-web-api

When I am calling below C# WebApi with POST request. It works fine when I have one parameter in method. Let say I want to include another parameter  `public HttpResponseMessage Post(Member member, bool IsAdmin)` then what would be value for `data: { id: 2012, firstName: 'FirstNameValue', lastName: 'LastNameValue' }`?

C#

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Member member)
    {
        try
        {
            var id = BusinessModule.PostMember(member);
            member.Id = id;
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Member>(HttpStatusCode.Created, member);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(VirtualPathUtility.AppendTrailingSlash(Request.RequestUri.ToString()) + member.Username);
            return response;
        }
        catch (MemberException e)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
            response.Content = new StringContent(e.Message);
            throw new HttpResponseException(response);
        }
    }
```

**Jquery**

```
 function postMember() {
            $.ajax({
                url: baseAddress,
                type: "POST",
                // Firefox reuires the dataType otherwise the "data" argument of the done callback
                // is just a string and not a JSON 
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                accept: "application/json",
                data: { id: 2012, firstName: 'FirstNameValue', lastName: 'LastNameValue' },
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#membersList").append('<li data-member=\'' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\'>' + data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName + '</i>');
            })
            .fail(function (e) {
                alert(e.statusText);
            })
            .always(function () { });
        }
```

Comment: not clear what you are even asking

Comment: **IsAdmin** is this just an example? If it isn't make sure you have read up on mass-assignment attacks http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx. Perhaps you could look at determining whether someone is admin via their security context e.g. claims, roles etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Web API does not deal with multiple posted content values.

See [here](http://techbrij.com/1026/pass-parameters-aspdotnet-webapi-jquery) an explanation, and possible workarounds.
I would put the new parameter in query string, and in the API method would read the variable from QueryString.

So, in **JQUery** you would have the next line:

```
url: baseAddress+"?IsAdmin=true",
```

And in **C#** would be:

```
bool IsAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(queryItems["IsAdmin"]);
```